# How Write AngularJs Code For Counting amt Qty & Column

Tags: angularjs

Here my intention is i wana to Count Quentity And Amout When User Enter the data into "TabCount" Div

**Table Structure**

```
Id       Name     Price    Qty     amt
---------------------------------------
1       Apple     10       1       10
2      Spares    100       2       300
3       Banaa    50        5       250
----------------------------------------
                    Qty--->8          Total-->560
```

Comment: JavaScript has loops, and has a `+` arithmetic operator. That should get you started.

Comment: could u plz mention the code or any Related url